# How to select the scala dataframe column with special character in it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am reading a json file where the key is having come special character. E.g

```
[{
        "ABB/aws:1.0/CustomerId:2.0": [{
            "id": 20,
            "namehash": "de8cfcde-95c5-47ac-a544-13db50557eaa"
        }]
}]
```

I am creating a scala dataframe and then trying to select the column using spark.sql "ABB/aws:1.0/CustomerId:2.0". Thats when its complaining about special character.

dataframe looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `backtick` to select column which has special characters. Check below code.

```
scala> df.select("`ABB/aws:1.0/CustomerId:2.0`").show(false)
+--------------------------------------------+
|ABB/aws:1.0/CustomerId:2.0                  |
+--------------------------------------------+
|[{20, de8cfcde-95c5-47ac-a544-13db50557eaa}]|
+--------------------------------------------+
```